# Function not able to apply to all cells #REF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets:
The first sheet is called "Raw Data" and the second is "Selected Product"

On the first sheet "Raw Data" I have 5 rows which are select, product code, product name, all size, and total size. The first rows which is selected is a checkbox, the second one is the product code, the third one is the product name, the fourth one is all sizes which will contain a few sizes available for example (S, M, L), and the fifth row is the total size which represents how many sizes are available in total count example (3)

On the second sheet "Selected product" has 3 rows which are product code, product name, and all size

**Question**
When I tick the select box on sheet 1 example product code is "AA1", the product name is "test", all size is "S, M, L" and the total size is 3. How can I populate these data to sheet 2 ? for example, when I tick a specific column on sheet 1, it will populate the product code : AA1 , product name: test, and all size S, M, L will separate into 3 columns to sheet 2

I already have all the formulas ready and working. But it just couldn't apply to every cell in "All size" on sheet 2. When I select more than 1 checkbox it will become #REF on sheet 2 "All Size".

[1 checkbox selected, its working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIfiZ.png)

**But when I select more than 1 checkbox it's not working**

Sheet 2 :
product code : =ARRAYFORMULA(Filter(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(FILTER('Raw Data'!$B$2:$B,'Raw Data'!$A$2:$A=TRUE)&"|",FILTER('Raw Data'!$E$2:$E,'Raw Data'!$A$2:$A=TRUE)),"|")),FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(FILTER('Raw Data'!$B$2:$B,'Raw Data'!$A$2:$A=TRUE)&"|",FILTER('Raw Data'!$E$2:$E,'Raw Data'!$A$2:$A=TRUE)),"|"))<>""))

product name :  =IF(A2="","",FILTER('Raw Data'!$C$2:$C,'Raw Data'!$B$2:$B=A2))

All size (I applied to all columns using the same formula): =IFERROR(IF(A2<>"", TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(INDEX(FILTER('Raw Data'!$D:$D, 'Raw Data'!$B:$B=A2), 0, 1), ",")), ""))

**GOOGLE SHEET:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JuPcJPrEzJL-2Ubx9UTnjDVhbwZFaMMJ29qtpqxStQE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr i just updated the google sheet on my question. Thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you try to drag it will collapse because it will overlap; or if you try to use it just as an ARRAYFORMULA it won't be able to divide into multiple cells

Here you have an option with REDUCE and SCAN, using that column E as an auxiliary to INDEX through the values in column D. Instead of joining and splitting, it just stacks sequentially:

```
=REDUCE({"Product Name","Product Code","Size"},FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A)),A:A),LAMBDA(h,e,{h;SCAN(,SEQUENCE(INDEX(E:E,e)),LAMBDA(a,v,{INDEX(B:B,e),INDEX(C:C,e),INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(D:D,e),",",1,1),v)}))}))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your method but the output doesnt appear on my side. here is my google sheet, can you help me to take a look ? thank u very much https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JuPcJPrEzJL-2Ubx9UTnjDVhbwZFaMMJ29qtpqxStQE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just add `'Raw Data!'` to every range! I've inserted it in column G of the same sheet and it works 